# $f(x) = x$ when $x$ is rational and $0$ when $x$ is irrational discontinous at all points other than $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, solution-verification, real-numbers

I want to show that $f(x) =
\begin{cases}
   x, & \text{$x$ is rational},\\ 0, & \text{$x$ is irrational}.
\end{cases} 
$

has discontinuities at all points other than $x = 0$, I'll just do the rational case as the irrational case is similar.

**Attempt:**
Usually I would find two different sequences that converge to the same value and show that when I apply $f$ to the sequences I get two different values.

**Question**
Am I able to instead apply $f$ to my sequence and then also apply $f$ to the value that the sequence converges to (rather than two different sequences), and show these give different values as below?

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{Q} - \{0\}$. There exists a sequence $\{t_{n}\} \in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ such that $t_{n} \rightarrow x$. Then $f(t_{n}) = 0$, but $f(x) = x$.

Hence $f$ is discontinuous at $\mathbb{Q} - \{0\}$

Comment: Compare also with the [standard proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138148/prove-that-f-is-not-continuous-anywhere-in-0-1-if-fx-0-when-x-irrati?rq=1).

Comment: For your sequence $t_n$, you might take (for instance) $t_n = x + \frac{\pi}{n}$. Though proving that $f$ is discontinuous at irrational points using this method is slightly trickier.

Comment: Quoting from the the citation from @DietrichBurde, the key point is that rational and irrational numbers are both dense in $\Bbb{R}.$  At $x = 0$, it is irrelevant, because in a neighborhood around $x = 0$, rational numbers will be *close* to $0$.  For any other value $x = x_0 \neq 0$, you have that in any neighborhood around $x_0$, there will be some instances of $f(x) = 0, $ and some instances of $f(x)$ being *close* to $x_0$.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @IAmAGuest the OP is asking us to check their proof of continuity.

Comment: @IAmAGuest  Am I allowed to use $f(x)$ not equalling $f(t_{n})$  to show that $f$ is discontinuous at the rationals excluding $0$. since usually don't you have to show you get different values of $f$ for two different sequences, but I am using a sequence $\{t_{n}\}$ and the value the sequence converges to, $x$

Comment: More generally, let $X$ be any *dense* subset of $\mathbb R$ (between any two real numbers $x<y$ there is a $z\in X$ such that $x<z<y$). The function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x&\text{if $x\in X$} \\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
is discontinuous everywhere, except at $0$.

Comment: Yes, it is enough to exhibit two subsequences that converge to distinct values (twice).

Comment: Another argument is that $\forall y:0<|x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|\ge x$ because every interval contains an irrational and a rational.